# How do I do the OPPOSITE of [RequireHttps(Redirect=true)] in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, requiressl

I know the easy way to get to an SSL page in ASP.NET MVC - via the [[RequireSSL] attribute](http://blog.salvoz.com/2009/04/25/PartialSSLAndAuthorizationWithAspNetMVCRevisited.aspx) but I'm a little confused to the best way to do the opposite.

I have many links on my site in a header bar and most of those links don't require SSL and I don't want to still use SSL.

The futures project makes it very easy to redirect automatically to an SSL page with `[RequireSSL(Redirect=true)]`, but it doesnt seem to make it easy to get out of this context and automatically redirect back to http.

What am I missing?

Comment: note this was renamed to RequireHttps in MVC 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not missing anything; there is no out-of-the-box functionality for this.  You can easily create your own by taking [the RequireSslAttribute source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/22929#391756) and modifying it.

Comment: does it make sense to do this? i cant see any issue with it myself, but then it leaves me wondering why it isnt a standard feature. am i going to get those annoying 'you have been redirected to an insecure page' errors?

Comment: It's not a standard feature because there isn't enough incentive to include it.  Similarly, [RequireSsl] hasn't been moved out of Futures and into the main binary because even though it's tested, it hasn't yet gone through specification, review, and documentation.

If you're concerned about warnings, perhaps it's best to generate HTTP links instead of HTTPS links in the first place.  There are Html.ActionLink() overloads that accept a protocol as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from a dupe question elsewhere:

[How to step out from https to http mode in asp.net mvc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566928/how-to-step-out-from-https-to-http-mode-in-asp-net-mvc)

**CAUTION**: If choosing to use this approach your auth cookie will be sent over plain text after switching back to HTTP, and can potentially be stolen and used by someone else. [See this](http://www.leastprivilege.com/PermaLink.aspx?guid=50a39e64-caab-4fbd-b8e1-2be06b2e6081). In other words - if you were using this for a bank site you would need to make sure that switching to http would **first** log the user out.

```
public class DoesNotRequireSSL: ActionFilterAttribute 
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
        {
                var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
                var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

                if (request.IsSecureConnection && !request.IsLocal) 
                {
                string redirectUrl = request.Url.ToString().Replace("https:", "http:");
                response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
                }
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is well worth reading (epecially to realize the security implications of switching carelessly back to `http` from `https` :

[Partially SSL Secured Web Apps With ASP.NET](http://www.leastprivilege.com/PermaLink.aspx?guid=50a39e64-caab-4fbd-b8e1-2be06b2e6081) - not MVC specific but relevant security concerns

[Partial SSL Website with ASP.NET MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/01/19/running-a-partial-ssl-website-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) - MVC friendly

It's quite a complicated issue overall. Still haven't found a true solution to everything I want to do, but thought these articles may help others.