# Overriding a global action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ssl

A handful of pages on my website need to use SSL, so I've added `[RequireHttps]` to the relevant controllers. However, I still want the majority of my pages to always use non-SSL so I successfully used [code I found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566928/how-to-step-out-from-https-to-http-mode-in-asp-net-mvc/1570437#1570437) to create a custom `[DoNotUseHttps]` filter.

To make things easier I'd like to include this non-SSL filter by default, so I added it to the global filters which are set in the Global.asax file. However, I seem to have now created an infinite loop with each filter redirecting to the other.

Which leads me to my question... is there anything I can add to my global filter to detect if the `[RequireHttps]` has been already applied to the controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can interrogate anything you like about the actions and controllers.  To check for `RequireHttpsAttribute`:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

    bool requireHttps = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute), true).Length > 0
 }
```